# constructor in class, when the object will be create?

Tags: class, oop, object, constructor

[image: **strong text**]

I have a class named A,Typically, like line 15, object "b" will be created.
So why in line 14 is not? I do not really understand when the subject is officially called and called to constructor

Comment: In C++, `A a();` is not a constructor syntax. Instead, it declares a method named `a` without arguments that returns an object of type `A`.

Comment: thank you, maybe i understood, it just a function was created in main function?. so a is not a object.

Comment: Yes, in your example, `a` is the name of a function, and not an object of type `A`.

Comment: You may want to study https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization. The _notes_ even mention your situation.